# I want to fetch the Column Name Of Small(Range,1)

Tags: excel

I want to fetch the Column Name Of Small(Range,1)

Ive a top row that has names on it. I want a cell that shows

Smallest out of the row with the name concatenated

Example it shows like this : ABC - 1000

If 1000 is the smallest number in the row it show concatenate 1000 with the name of the top row above 1000.

Can anyone help me with the solution.

Comment: I know this explanation makes sense to you, but you are looking at the data, please allow us the same courtesy.  Please post a mock up of the data or at least a picture of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula below,

```
=A1&" "&SMALL(A2:A5,1)
```

Where, A1 is the row name and A2:A5 is the range